# Is there any reason not to create a class or struct to resolve a 'non boolean' boolean

Tags: c#

I am just a hobby programmer but I come across may cases where I want to switch a type value (e.g. label.backgroundcolor) depending on whether it has been clicked or not, or whether the mouse is over or not. This is normally a trivial change but there has to be code for the event in each case and this then involves passing information such as default colour, mouse-over colour or default fontstyle, mouse-over fontstyle or any of many other types of 'switch'. In all cases it is simply a case of toggling the change between one value and another but, because this could potentially happen over several different types (Labels, Textboxes, Panels etc.) I find I have to code for each type separately.

Is there any good reason why I shouldn't just do this

```
class AnyObjectBoolean
{
    private object objOne;
    private object objTwo;

    public AnyObjectBoolean(object oneValue, object twoValue)
    {
        objOne = oneValue;
        objTwo = twoValue;
    }

    public object invert(Object val)
    {

        if (val.ToString() == objOne.ToString())
        {
            return objTwo; 
        }
        else
        {
            return objOne;
        }
    }
```

I then create a new instance for each object and style I want to change and the resulting event code becomes (for instance)

```
private void Label_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Label = (Label)sender;
        Label.BackColor = (Color)SelectColours.invert(Label.BackColor);
    }
```

where SelectColours is an instance of AnyObjectBoolean.

Maybe not a great question but I ask because I've never found anything like this implemented anywhere.

Disclaimer:- this is my first post so I may not have tagged entirely appropriately or completely.

Comment: How will you know that `object sender` can be cast to a `Label`?

Comment: How many times are you reusing the `SelectColours` class? And could it not be replaced by a *function*?

Comment: This is not how you compare objects.

Comment: @DiskCrasher If it's the `sender` of an event handler which is only ever subscribed to a `Label`'s `MouseClick` event, which is suggested by the handler's name, that cast is safe.

Comment: @hvd Yes, but the question states several different types (Labels, Textboxes, Panels etc.).

Comment: Is there any good reason why we shouldn't write classes which encapsulate some logic not provided out of the box?

Comment: For this particular example I would say that separating concerns is the way to go. One concern is whether something is on or off, another concern is how to visualize whether that something is on or off. Don't confuse the two. The first concern can be handled by a simple `bool` variable, the other concern by a simple expression (since you only deal with colors): `isOnOrOff ? onColor : offColor`.

Comment: Maybe if you list all the possible situations and properties you want to change, we can find a way to find a better approach for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all welcome to StackOverflow.

Personally, I'd prefer to handle this through a catch-all function, in which I would deal with all the types of objects that I wanted.  Something like:

```
private Color ToggleColor(object sender, Color currentColor)
{
    Color labelBackColor = Color.White;
    Color labelHoverColor = Color.Yellow;
    Color textBackColor = Color.Wheat;
    Color textHoverColor = Color.Turquoise;
    Color defaultBackColor = Color.Tomato;
    Color defaultHoverColor = Color.SteelBlue;

    Label l = sender as Label;
    if (l != null)
    {
        return currentColor == labelBackColor ? labelHoverColor : labelBackColor;
    }
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    if (t != null)
    {
        return currentColor == textBackColor ? textHoverColor : textBackColor;
    }

    return currentColor == defaultBackColor ? defaultHoverColor : defaultBackColor;
}
```

Doing it this way, I keep the entire color scheme in one place.  BTW don't use my suggested colors!  Note the use of "as".  It does the same as cast, with the important difference that it does not throw an Exception if it fails, it simply returns null.  Therefore, you can simply try each object in turn safely until you get a hit.

Comment: He also wants to change font style and some other possible settings.

Comment: @Andrew Two possibilities - either have a ToggleFont function the same way as ToggleColor, or have a generic ToggleProperty function, in which you have a third parameter being an enum of properties, and then do a switch statement.  Personally I prefer one function per property, especially since it means the return type will be a fixed type, rather than one of several properties, when you will need to cast.

Comment: This seems to answer the question and gives a nice way of dealing with the toggle. Also, thanks for showing the use of "as". I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no need for an instance, as i understand your program static class will be more appropriate here and you can change it from outside whenever you need.
2. use one method that will add events to all controls (you can add click event to all control types not just a label).

**I think you want to do something like that:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyColors.firstColor = Color.Blue;
        MyColors.secondColor = Color.Yellow;
        // add events to all requested controls
        AddEvent(new Control[] {
        label1,
        label2,
        label3,
    });

    }

    public void AddEvent(Control[] myControls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in myControls)
        {
            c.MouseClick += Control_Click;
        }
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).BackColor = MyColors.GetColor(((Control)sender).BackColor);
    }
}

static class MyColors
{
    public static Color firstColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    public static Color secondColor { get; set; } = Color.White;

    public static Color GetColor(Color color)
    {
        if (color == firstColor)
        {
            return secondColor;
        }
        else
        {
            return firstColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the controls such as `TextBox`, `Label` and many other controls inherit from the `Control` class. The property `BackColor` is a property of the `Control` class; therefore, you can write a method or a class that takes a `Control` type and changes its color. Below is a class which takes 2 colors in its constructors and then inverts the passed in `Control` instance from one color to another.

```
public class ColorInverter
{
    public Color Color1 { get; private set; }
    public Color Color2 { get; private set; }

    public ColorInverter(Color color1, Color color2)
    {
        this.Color1 = color1;
        this.Color2 = color2;
    }

    public void Invert(Control control)
    {
        if (control.BackColor == this.Color1)
        {
            control.BackColor = this.Color2;
            return;
        }

        control.BackColor = Color1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ColorInverter c = new ColorInverter(Color.Black, Color.Red);
TextBox box = new TextBox();
c.Invert(box);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(v=vs.110).aspx) is the inheritance hierarchy for `Label`. You can look for other controls there as well.

You may even check if the control inherits `Control` before calling the `Invert` method:

```
if (box is Control)
{
    c.Invert(box);
}
else
{
    // ...do something
}
```

You can use access any properties such as `FontSize`, `FontFamily` and many other [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.110).aspx) properties as well. Obviously change the class name from `ColorInverter` to something else if you want to change the `FontSize` etc. as well.